# Select all elements when all checkboxes unchecked

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I am working on a webpage that would display a list of products with several attributes (color, size, style). I would need that when all checkboxes are unchecked, the page would show all the products, and just when I start checking one the categories will it start filtering the products. Is that possible with checklist-model? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use checklist-model (http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/ if you are refreeing this)
Have the code below which will tell you how can you do it just add the filtering logic to it.

Controller code

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
//On controller load show all the products
$scope.filters = ['color','style','size'];
$scope.allproducts = [];
$scope.selectedFilters = {
    filters: []
};

$scope.applyFilter = function (filters)
{
    //Add filtering logic to filter objects from allproducts 
    //according to filter values in the filters array passed in the function.
    //the data will be changed in if filter applied to allproducts array as allproducts in binded in view.

}


$scope.$watchCollection('$scope.selectedFilters.filters', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    //If all values are unchecked
    if($scope.selectedFilters.filters.length == 0)
    {
        //Show All products
    }
    else {
        //Show the filtered products
        applyFilter($scope.selectedFilters.filters) ;   
       } 
}); });
```

View code:

```
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <label ng-repeat="filter in filters">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedFilters.filters" checklist-value="filter"> {{filter}}
    </label>
    <label ng-repeat="product in allproducts">{{product}}</label> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I was referring to that directive. It works perfect, I mark it as valid.